# Batch grab all font files

Tags: windows-7, batch

I'm not too great at Batch but I am fairly sure it can do this despite not seeing any other questions/pages on this.

**My Issue:**
I have a series of font files (`.otf` and `.ttf`) within a folder. Some are in the root directory whereas others are in sub-directories or even sub-directories of those. What I want to do is move/copy all font files to another folder. All of the folders and sub-directories have random names so I can't write them in. The only thing that is static is the folder I want to move them to.

**Question:**
Is what I need to do possible to start of with and if so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively.

This will gather the files.

```
FOR /R C:\Windows\System32 %%F IN (*.OTF, *.TTF) DO ECHO "%%F" >> fonts.txt
```

This will copy them.

```
@echo off
SET destfolder=C:\fonts\
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (fonts.txt) DO COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

Powershell is better suited at theses tasks.

Comment: I changed the folders and the `COPY` to `MOVE /y` and ran them. I get the following error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: I should have also mentioned that I'm open to any Powershell solutions.

Comment: I also get a `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` but it still moves the files.  That did not happen for you.

Comment: it moved some but not all of them.

Comment: Using powershell do something like this. `Get-Content fonts.txt|Foreach-Object{move-item -path $_.FullName -destination "path_to_destination"}`

Comment: I just got spammed with this error: http://i.imgur.com/57Yt9RO.png

Comment: It is because there is no error checking in it.  Try rerunning the batch script to gather the fonts files than the powershell to move.

Comment: Having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what the question asks but my friend suggested something so simple. Use the Windows' file search to find the file types and move them from there.

Example:
[image]